# Numpy vectorize from x*y array to x*y*3

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a function to convert an integer into a tuple of length 3, and up until now I've been doing nested for loops and a cache, but it's still quite slow. The function pre calculates values and caches them in a list, then does a bit of maths with `__getitem__` to figure out which value to return. This is then called millions of times with different numbers.

I've recently started using numpy, and I'd like to speed up the process as much as possible. The initial optimisation I did (divide the entire numpy array to match the cache length so `__getitem__` can be bypassed) sped up one example from 15 to 3 seconds, and I'd like to try out vectorize if possible.

The only issue is I can't figure out how I can get a `w*h` array into a `w*h*3` one using vectorize, and wondering if anyone knows how? I've looked into adding an extra dimension but it seemed more of a reshape type thing.

Here's some example code:

```
>>> height, width = 2, 5

>>> array = numpy.arange(width * height).reshape(height, width)
[[0 1 2 3 4]
 [5 6 7 8 9]]

>>> test_list = [(0, i, 0) for i in range(width * height)]
>>> numpy.vectorize(test_list.__getitem__)(array)
(array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]), array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]), array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]))

#expected = [[(0, 0, 0) (0, 1, 0) (0, 2, 0) (0, 3, 0) (0, 4, 0)]
#            [(0, 5, 0) (0, 6, 0) (0, 7, 0) (0, 8, 0) (0, 9, 0)]]
```

Comment: `numpy.vectorize` **does not improve performance**. As the docs say, "The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop." More generally, if the result you are looking for is a *list of tuples*, then probably `numpy` is not the right tool,

Comment: The conversion to numpy appears to help a lot with preparing the array for the lookup, but you're possibly right with writing it back to a normal list, I'll test it out for speed compared to the answer :)

Comment: I'm not sure if it will help, but remember that numpy can use arrays as indexes.

Comment: What I still don't understand is what sort of data you are working with, i.e., is the list of tuples always *ascending from 0*?

Comment: Sorry, tried to keep it vague as the specifics weren't too important, may not have got that across though haha. My array contains integers between 0 and n, and the list I'm using is a range of RGB values, and has a much smaller range. As the arrays generally contain millions of values, the non numpy way is not very fast at all :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use assignment in this case:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> height, width = 2, 5
>>> array = np.arange(width * height).reshape(height, width)
>>> res = np.zeros((height, width, 3), dtype=array.dtype)
>>> res[:, :, 1].flat = array.ravel()
>>> res
array([[[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0],
        [0, 2, 0],
        [0, 3, 0],
        [0, 4, 0]],

       [[0, 5, 0],
        [0, 6, 0],
        [0, 7, 0],
        [0, 8, 0],
        [0, 9, 0]]])
```

In case you want tuples, you're probably better off using a normal `for` loop and plain lists:

```
>>> lst = array.tolist()
>>> res = [[(0, item, 0) for item in sublst] for sublst in lst]
>>> res 
[[(0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 2, 0), (0, 3, 0), (0, 4, 0)],
 [(0, 5, 0), (0, 6, 0), (0, 7, 0), (0, 8, 0), (0, 9, 0)]]
```

Both approaches are (probably) faster than `np.vectorize` which is just a convenience function, not for performance.

Comment: First one doesn't really do the job as I still need the list lookup (I used `(0, i, 0)` as an example only), 2nd one is great though. On a 1280x720 array, the cached lookup takes 7 seconds, my improved one takes 1.24 seconds, your `tolist()` one takes 0.05 seconds, thanks :D